# mplayer text mode set screen dimentions

Tags: command-line, video, mplayer, youtube-dl

I'm using this command to watch youtube videos from command line

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19jv0HM92kw -o - | mplayer -vo caca   -
```

and I find it very amusing. However the player only shows on portion of my screen and I can't figure out on how to change the screen dimentions, as the mplayer arguments dont work (probably need to find how to pass  arguments to libaa caca driver). Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set CACA_GEOMETRY environment before run mplayer, like:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19jv0HM92kw -o - | CACA_GEOMETRY=80x25 mplayer -vo caca   -
```

(google power, 1st hit: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/caca.html )